# F# System.OutOfMemoryException with recursive call

Tags: recursion, f#, out-of-memory, tail-recursion

This is actually a solution to Project Euler [Problem 14](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=14) in F#. However, I'm running into a System.OutOfMemory exception when attempting to calculate an iterative sequence for larger numbers. As you can see, I'm writing my recursive function with tail calls.

I was running into a problem with StackOverFlowException because I was debugging in visual studio (which disables the tail calls). I've documented that [in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111390/f-using-accumulator-still-getting-stack-overflow-exception). Here, I'm running in release mode--but I'm getting out of memory exceptions when I run this as a console app (on windows xp with 4gb ram).

I'm really at a loss to understand how I coded myself into this memory overflow & hoping someone can show my the error in my ways.

```
let E14_interativeSequence x =

  let rec calc acc startNum =
    match startNum with
    | d when d = 1      -> List.rev (d::acc)
    | e when e%2 = 0    -> calc (e::acc) (e/2)
    | _                 -> calc (startNum::acc) (startNum * 3 + 1)

  let maxNum pl=

    let rec maxPairInternal acc pairList =
        match pairList with
        | []        ->  acc
        | x::xs     ->  if (snd x) > (snd acc) then maxPairInternal x xs
                        else maxPairInternal acc xs

    maxPairInternal (0,0) pl
    |> fst

  // if I lower this to like [2..99999] it will work.
  [2..99999] 
  |> List.map (fun n -> (n,(calc [] n)))
  |> List.map (fun pair -> ((fst pair), (List.length (snd pair))))
  |> maxNum
  |> (fun x-> Console.WriteLine(x))
```

---

**EDIT**

Given the suggestions via the answers, I rewrote to use a lazy list and also to use Int64's.

```
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

let E14_interativeSequence =

  let rec calc acc startNum =
    match startNum with
    | d when d = 1L         -> List.rev (d::acc) |> List.toSeq
    | e when e%2L = 0L      -> calc (e::acc) (e/2L)
    | _                     -> calc (startNum::acc) (startNum * 3L + 1L)

  let maxNum (lazyPairs:LazyList<System.Int64*System.Int64>) =

    let rec maxPairInternal acc (pairs:seq<System.Int64*System.Int64>) =
        match pairs with
        | :? LazyList<System.Int64*System.Int64> as p ->
            match p with
            | LazyList.Cons(x,xs)->  if (snd x) > (snd acc) then maxPairInternal x xs
                                     else maxPairInternal acc xs
            | _                         ->  acc
        | _ -> failwith("not a lazylist of pairs")

    maxPairInternal (0L,0L) lazyPairs
    |> fst

  {2L..999999L}
  |> Seq.map (fun n -> (n,(calc [] n)))
  |> Seq.map (fun pair -> ((fst pair), (Convert.ToInt64(Seq.length (snd pair)))))
  |> LazyList.ofSeq
  |> maxNum
```

which solves the problem. I'd also look at Yin Zhu's solution which is better, though.

Comment: As @Brian pointed out, Seq is better suited for this problem. Indeed, having worked through the first 45 problems in Project Euler, I found almost all of them are best suited for Seq-based solutions. If you're interested, here's my solution to problem 14: http://projecteulerfun.blogspot.com/2010/05/problem-14-which-starting-number-under.html (of course, you may want to wait to compare until after you've worked yours out to satisfaction, or you may be at the point where you're content with your algorithm but would like to see how a Seq-based implementation looks).

Comment: warning, there is at least one other problem besides the OutOfMemoryException with your solution which might be spoiled by looking at my solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by Brian, `List.*` operations are not appropriate here. They cost too much memory.

The stackoverflow problem comes from another place. There are two possible for you to have stackoverflow: `calc` and `maxPairInternal`. It must be the first as the second has the same depth as the first. Then the problem comes to the numbers, the number in `3n+1` problem could easily go to very large. So you first get a int32 overflow, then you get a stackoverflow. That's the reason. After changing the numbers to 64bit, the program works.

[Here is my solution page](http://fsharp-euler.wikispaces.com/euler+014), where you can see a memoization trick.

```
open System
let E14_interativeSequence x =

  let rec calc acc startNum =
    match startNum with
    | d when d = 1L      -> List.rev (d::acc)
    | e when e%2L = 0L    -> calc (e::acc) (e/2L)
    | _                 -> calc (startNum::acc) (startNum * 3L + 1L)

  let maxNum pl=

    let rec maxPairInternal acc pairList =
        match pairList with
        | []        ->  acc
        | x::xs     ->  if (snd x) > (snd acc) then maxPairInternal x xs
                        else maxPairInternal acc xs

    maxPairInternal (0L,0) pl
    |> fst

  // if I lower this to like [2..99999] it will work.
  [2L..1000000L] 
  |> Seq.map (fun n -> (n,(calc [] n)))
  |> Seq.maxBy (fun (n, lst) -> List.length lst)
  |> (fun x-> Console.WriteLine(x))
```

Comment: +1 good catch @Yin. I had noted the presence of the int32 overflow in the OP's code, but didn't make the connection to the out of memory exception; when I faced the same flaw in my own solution, it resulted in non-termination since my strategy didn't involve actually constructing collatz chains, rather just counting their lengths.

Comment: yea. I wouldn't have figured it out. . .

Comment: @Kevin Won: if you suspect, or want to test for, integer overflow happening in your code, add `open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked` to your script. This replaces integer operators with ones that throw when they overflow. It makes your calculations (slightly) slower, so don't forget to remove it when it isn't needed anymore.

Comment: @cfern: nice. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

If you change List.map to Seq.map (and re-work maxPairInternal to iterate over a seq) that will probably help tons.  Right now, you're manifesting all the data at once in a giant structure before processing the whole structure to get a single number result.  It is much better to do this lazily via Seq, and just create one row, and compare it with the next row, and create a single row at a time and then discard it.

I don't have time to code my suggestion now, but let me know if you are still having trouble and I'll revisit this.

Answer (score 2):

Stop trying to use lists everywhere, this isn't Haskell! And stop writing `fst pair` and `snd pair` everywhere, this isn't Lisp!

If you want a simple solution in F# you can do it directly like this without creating any intermediate data structures:

```
let rec f = function
  | 1L -> 0
  | n when n % 2L = 0L -> 1 + f(n / 2L)
  | n -> 1 + f(3L * n + 1L)

let rec g (li, i) = function
  | 1L -> i
  | n -> g (max (li, i) (f n, n)) (n - 1L)

let euler14 n = g (0, 1L) n
```

That takes around 15s on my netbook. If you want something more time efficient, reuse previous results via an array:

```
let rec inside (a : _ array) n =
  if n <= 1L || a.[int n] > 0s then a.[int n] else
    let p =
      if n &&& 1L = 0L then inside a (n >>> 1) else
        let n = 3L*n + 1L
        if n < int64 a.Length then inside a n else outside a n
    a.[int n] <- 1s + p
    1s + p
and outside (a : _ array) n =
  let n = if n &&& 1L = 0L then n >>> 1 else 3L*n + 1L
  1s + if n < int64 a.Length then inside a n else outside a n

let euler14 n =
  let a = Array.create (n+1) 0s
  let a = Array.Parallel.init (n+1) (fun n -> inside a (int64 n))
  let i = Array.findIndex (Array.reduce max a |> (=)) a
  i, a.[i]
```

That takes around 0.2s on my netbook.

Comment: @jon: outside of style prefs, what are the reasons why you object to Lists and pair functions? I'm trying to understand your perspective & why you think that my solve is an abuse. While F# certainly isn't Haskell or Lisp, it certainly has a lineage that draws on both parents.

Comment: Lists can be a great collection when there are few (preferably zero) elements, particularly in the context of logic programming, but that is not the case here so they are not suitable in this case. The `fst` and `snd` functions are almost always better avoided in favor of pattern matching.

Comment: Instead of writing `d when d=1` (which looks like `COND` in Lisp) you should simply write the pattern `1`. Don't give `startNum` the aliases `d` and `e`, it is confusing, use the same name throughout. Replace `x::xs ->  if (snd x) > ..` with `(_, v as x)::xs ->  if v > ..`. Replace `fun pair -> ((fst pair), (List.length (snd pair)))` with `fun (k, v) -> k, List.length v`, removing the superfluous parentheses as well as the unnecessary and inefficient `fst` and `snd` leaving shorter and faster code.

Comment: Never build big lists of anything, particularly consecutive ints like `[2..99999]`. Deforest your pipelines. Don't eagerly build arbitrarily-long lists just to count their lengths. Never introduce unnecessary run-time type tests. Lazy lists are virtually useless in practice so you'd need a compelling reason to pull them in and, in this case, they have only served to mask the underlying problems with your approach.

Comment: I thought it looked Haskellish and, now that I come to search for Haskell solutions, your code looks like a literal translation of the first solution from the Haskell wiki. You need to be *very* careful when you try to translate Haskell code because Haskell programs tend to lack the essence of what makes programs computable in the real world, i.e. predictable time and space.

Answer (score 0):

Found this looking for Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.Checked.
I'm just learning F#, so I thought I'd take the Project Euler 14 Challenge.

This uses recursion but not tail-recursion.
Takes about 3.1 sec for me, but has the advantage that I can almost understand it.

```
let Collatz (n:int64) = if n % 2L = 0L then n / 2L else n * 3L + 1L

let rec CollatzLength (current:int64) (acc:int) =
    match current with 
    | 1L -> acc
    | _ -> CollatzLength (Collatz current) (acc + 1)

let collatzSeq (max:int64) = 
    seq{
        for i in 1L..max do
            yield i, CollatzLength i 0
    }

let collatz = Seq.toList(collatzSeq 1000000L)

let result, steps = List.maxBy snd collatz
```