# cannot debug f# recursive function line by line - VS 2013

Tags: debugging, recursion, f#

I try to debug the recursive function to confirm my reasoning that this actually isn't tail recursion.
Below is working piece of code:

```
    let CountList list =
       let rec TailCountList list acc =
           match list with
           | [] -> acc
           | h::t -> TailCountList t  acc + 1

       TailCountList list 0

    printfn "%d" <| CountList [1;2;3;4;5;6]
```

I can place the breakpoint inside the function, but during debugging whole function is highlited and I can't make line by line steps. I am using VS 2013 Pro. I tried to play with compiler flags, but that doesn't seem to fix the issue.

Comment: How about a working example?

Comment: I apologize, didn't pay enough attention when pasting. Should work now.

Comment: For me it breaks on the case which is matched, so it hits the second case several times and then the first case.  Also, I think you want `TailCountList t  (acc + 1)`, otherwise its not tail-recursive (the + 1 is executed after `TailCountList` is evaluated).

Comment: Your suggestion about tail recursion is exactly what I wanted to confirm by looking into stack trace. The other way to write this is `TailCountList t <| acc + 1`.

Comment: have you resolved your issue?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did reproduce the issue with VS 2013 Express for Desktop. Whenever I place a breakpoint in one of the match cases and run debug, the breakpoint gets removed to the line where `TailCountList` definition starts. Whole function body gets highlited and is treated as a single debug step.

Comment: @GrzegorzSławecki: I can repro.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about the latest versions of F#/VS, but I believe that tail calls are disabled in debug mode anyway, so even without your breakpoint problem, I don't know if you'd be able to reproduce what you want. (http://stackoverflow.com/a/1416436)

Comment: I updated VS 2013 with SP2, but the issue stil exists.

Comment: I submitted a bug to VS: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/889970/unable-to-debug-f-recursive-function-step-by-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experience isn't perfect, but this does work.  Put your breakpoint on the line with the `match` and things are gravy.

[image]

I know you've taken the time to open a SO question, and to open a Connect bug, but pretty please can you log this on the Visual F# open source page? https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create

This isn't specific to recursive functions. It's just that overall the behavior around setting breakpoints is kind of funky right now in F#.  It would be great to have a handful of concrete examples logged in a bug.

Comment: The workaround has no effect on my machine. It still highlights whole function. However, Your post does answer original questing confirming that this is a tool issue. Following Your advice i submitted this to Visual F# Tools team: https://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/83

Comment: Have you tried unchecking "Enable Just My Code" in Tools -> Options -> Debugging? I am reproing the issue when it is checked, but it works as shown above (and actually also works to set bp on lines 4, 5, and 6) when I uncheck it.